# INNER JOIN me saltea un registro

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Me gustaría saber que estoy haciendo mal, he hecho una consulta con inner joins que debería mostrar 11 registros y solo me muestra 10, el decimo registro se lo salta, no sé si esté haciendo mal los join o se me haya pasado algún campo, les anexo imagenes y mis tablas, les agradezco mucho su tiempo!

Tabla Asset (arriba)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tabla branch (arriba)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla Supplier (arriba)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla Supply (arriba)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla Data (arriba)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi query

```
SELECT * FROM branch A
INNER JOIN asset B ON (A.Id = B.Branch_Id)
INNER JOIN supplier C ON ( A.Id = B.Branch_Id AND B.Branch_Id = C.Branch_Id)
INNER JOIN supply D ON (C.Id = D.Supplier_Id)
INNER JOIN data E ON (D.Id = E.Supply_Id AND B.Id = E.Asset_Id)
ORDER BY E.Intake
```

Datos de Asset
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Datos de Branch
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Datos de Supplier
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Datos de Supply
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Datos de Data
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Salida del query
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nuevamente les agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Alguno de tus registros relacionados es nulo?

Comment: No hermano, pero el valor de branch_id del decimo registro es 2, será que se estará filtrando por eso?

Comment: la única forma en que podamos contestar eso es viendo los datos de cada tabla

Comment: Pero te recomiendo que vayas ejecutando tu query por partes. Primero ejecuta hasta el primer `INNER JOIN`, revisa cuántas filas te devuelve; luego ejecuta hasta el segundo….y así, hasta que veas cuál `INNER JOIN` es el que elimina alguna fila. Así sabrás la tabla en la que tienes problemas

Comment: Ya mismo edito y publico los datos y la salida del query, gracias!

Comment: y que dato de toda esta maraña decis que te falta y deberia estar?

Comment: ufff….el modelo de datos tiene varios problemas. No deberías tener que usar condiciones de la misma columna de una tabla en diferentes joins (por ejemplo Asset_Id).

Comment: de hecho lo tenia sin la segunda condición e igual, la puse más que nada por desesperación.

Comment: una pregunta? , para que un and en los inner join si son los mismo de arriba, no me cabe en la cabeza, diría que tus join están en ese sentido , lo probaría sin los 'and' y solo guiándome por un datos para compararlo

Comment: probaba al aire nada más hehe, pero si en el último join considero que se necesita ya que en data se encuentran esos dos id's

Answer (score 0):

La condición que te esconde el registro 10 diría que es:

```sql
INNER JOIN supplier C ON ( A.Id = B.Branch_Id AND B.Branch_Id = C.Branch_Id)
```

En la tabla "supplier" no tienes Branch_Id con valor "2"...

Answer (score 0):

Lo más probable es que en uno de tus `INNER JOIN` hay un dato nulo o que no existe. Lo que yo haría es cambiar cada uno de mis `INNER JOIN` por `LEFT JOIN` a tu tabla principal `branch` de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT * FROM branch A
LEFT JOIN asset B ON (A.Id = B.Branch_Id) -- Primero este ponemos en LEFT JOIN
INNER JOIN supplier C ON ( A.Id = B.Branch_Id AND B.Branch_Id = C.Branch_Id)
INNER JOIN supply D ON (C.Id = D.Supplier_Id)
INNER JOIN data E ON (D.Id = E.Supply_Id AND B.Id = E.Asset_Id)
ORDER BY E.Intake
```

De esta forma cuando ejecutes la consulta podrás ver si una o más columnas retorna valores nulos. Tratando de adivinar creo que es muy probable que tu problema esté en donde haces los `INNER JOIN` con condiciones:

```
INNER JOIN supplier C ON ( A.Id = B.Branch_Id AND B.Branch_Id = C.Branch_Id)
```

Así que quizás esos dos quieras probar con `LEFT JOIN` para verificar.

> Esto te va a servir nada mas para saber si hay inconsistencia de
>   datos en tu tabla, y de ahí que puedas tomar una decisión.

Comment: Si revisas los comentarios, ya se le pregunto si tiene registros null a lo cual indico no tener ninguno así